# Beacon_Triangulation_python_centroid

Tags: python, algorithm, triangulation, beacon, rssi

1. I am working on Beacon Triangulation Algorithm using Python. I have beacon data from the reader and calculating the distance using RSSI value. can anyone please guide me how to approach this method?
2. I am reading a text file which has large no of RSSI values. I am unable to process these large no of values. Let say I have 30 RSSI values in a file. How can I calculate 30 distance values using these values?
3. Any method to calculate the centroid of the intersection of three circles?

Thanks

Comment: You should show the code you have written to solve this problem.  Once you have that, you can rewrite your question to ask how to help solve any problems with your code in order to achieve your goal.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  [Downvoted](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)